# Host C# rest service - Error on return type

Tags: c#, rest

I'm trying to host a **Rest service** i created in **c#**, deploying a **.dll** file and importing it in a new project with main method.

To create an host in the main I created an interface for my Rest service, but after the declaration of this interface i keep getting the error

> "The name Content does not exist in the current context"

. Content is the return of my method, that should return only **void** or **Task** or **Task T>** because is **async** method.
How should I resolve this error?

This is part of the ***controller***(Rest Service):

```
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Configuration;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Http.Headers;
    using System.Security.Cryptography;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Web.Http;
    using System.ServiceModel;
    using Couchbase;
    using Couchbase.Core;
    using Couchbase.IO;
    using JWT;



    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ApiController
    {
        Task<IHttpActionResult> SignUp(LoginModel model);
    }

    namespace Nerder_Backend.Controllers
    {
        [RoutePrefix("api/user")]
        public class UserController : ApiController
        {
            private readonly IBucket _bucket = ClusterHelper.GetBucket(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("CouchbaseUserBucket"));
            private readonly string _secretKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["JWTTokenSecret"];

            [Route("signup")]
            [HttpPost]
            public async Task<IHttpActionResult> SignUp(LoginModel model)
            {
                if (model == null || !model.IsValid())
                {
                    return Content(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, new Error("Invalid email and/or password"));
                }

 var userKey = CreateUserKey(model.Email);
            if (await _bucket.ExistsAsync(userKey))
            {
                return Content(HttpStatusCode.Conflict, new Error($"email '{model.Email}' already exists"));
            }

            var userDoc = new Document<User>
            {
                Id = userKey,
                Content = new User
                {
                    Email = model.Email,
                    Password = CalcuateMd5Hash(model.Password)
                },
                Expiry = model.Expiry
            };

            var result = await _bucket.InsertAsync(userDoc);
            if (!result.Success)
            {
                return Content(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, new Error(result.Message));
            }

            var data = new
            {
                token = BuildToken(model.Email)
            };
            var context = $"Created user with ID '{userKey}' in bucket '{_bucket.Name}' that expires in {userDoc.Expiry}ms";
            return Content(HttpStatusCode.Accepted, new Result(data, context));
        }
```

This is the ***main*** method :

```
namespace MockServer
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8080/signup");

            // Create the ServiceHost.
            using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(UserController), baseAddress))
            {
                // Enable metadata publishing.
                ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
                smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
                smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;
                host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);

                // Open the ServiceHost to start listening for messages. Since
                // no endpoints are explicitly configured, the runtime will create
                // one endpoint per base address for each service contract implemented
                // by the service.
                host.Open();

                Console.WriteLine("The service is ready at {0}", baseAddress);
                Console.WriteLine("Press <Enter> to stop the service.");
                Console.ReadLine();

                // Close the ServiceHost.
                host.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Getting conflicts because your interface has the same name of `System.Web.Http.ApiController`. While that class has a `Content` method, your interface does not. Hence the error. You also seem to be mixing technology stacks. Was the intention to use WCF or ASP.Net Web API?

Comment: My intention was to use ASP.Net Web API.
And the problem is on my return type, because it seems Content is not a Task type. But That's how you I'm supposed to return an HTTP response.
If I change ApiController name still have the same error.

Comment: Then this looks like you want to self host asp.net web api. I suggest you look up that topic. The code in main above is for WCF.

Comment: Show the whole SignUp method. if the method is awaited then sure you can return content. if not then you will have to use `Task.FromResult` to wrap it in a Task.

Comment: It has Async methods, I've updated.
Could I just wrap Content in a Task? that will be ok for me

Comment: And the main method is just a test, but thanks for the advice, I'll change it next to have solved my service error into a ASP.Net.

Comment: Code in controller looks correct. Get rid of the conflicting interface and that should fix the problem with the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Update main to host the web api properly.

include the following using statements

```
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.SelfHost; //install the nuget package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.SelfHost
```

update `Program` class to Host the Web API

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var baseAddress = "http://localhost:8080";
        var config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration(baseAddress);
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();//map attribute routes
        // Create the server
        using (var server = new HttpSelfHostServer(config)) {
            server.OpenAsync().Wait();
            Console.WriteLine("The service is ready at {0}", baseAddress);
            Console.WriteLine("Press <Enter> to stop the service.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Now make sure the api controller it correctly defined.

```
[RoutePrefix("api/user")]
public class UserController : ApiController {
    private readonly IBucket _bucket = ClusterHelper.GetBucket(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("CouchbaseUserBucket"));
    private readonly string _secretKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["JWTTokenSecret"];
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("signup")] //Matches POST api/user/signup
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> SignUp(LoginModel model) {

        //...code removed for brevity

    }
}
```

Given the program set and controller attribute routes,  the action would be found at

```
POST http://localhost:8080/api/user/signup
```